# How to behave while trying out recommendations

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions, comments, etiquette

What's the proper way to update a question while testing out suggestions? For example, I asked for [Podcast app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7240/podcast-app-for-android) suggestions. Now I'm trying out a couple of the suggested apps and a few that I found on my own.

Should I start adding an answer for each of the apps that I have finished testing/trying as some sort of review? (for apps suggested as answers I guess I should add a comment stating how it worked out for me instead of adding a new answer) and when I make a final decision should I mark one of the options as accepted?

Or should I just do all my testing and just mark an answer and give some comments?

I'm asking in part because I don't want to leave the question in an apparently 'abandoned' state while checking the options out. Sometimes tryouts take a few days =b

Answer (score 14):

Well, it's pretty normal that testing recommended solutions is not done "ad-hoc". On some SE sites, I've marked questions accepted several months after they've been given: if evaluation takes time, it takes time. So don't feel pushed just because of that.

On the other hand, if you think you *might* have found an answer being the solution, you can also go ahead and mark it such. If you decide otherwise later (e.g. because another answer popped up matching a lot better), you still can "move your mark".

Leaving a comment on a question you're just evaluating is a nice gesture to the answerer. But there's no need for a "progress bar". When you finished evaluating one solution, and found it not fitting, you can always leave a comment like "thanks, looks great, but doesn't fit because..." to show what was going on. If the answer showed effort in being given, and *principially* matches your question, you can always honor that by an upvote – even if it turned out to not fully match your needs. Upvoting is the SE way to say "thanks" :)

TL;DR:

I'm pretty sure everyone recommending a software and specifying how it matches your needs is aware you cannot say straight away if it really fits you. So take your time, and don't feel pressed.

Comment: `not done "ad-hoc"`: I am not sure to understand. Do you mean `not done immediately`?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul No. Rather `not COMPLETED immediately`. It usually takes time, it's nothing you do as fast as clicking your fingers :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Izzy's answer, I would say that in some cases you might also **edit** an answer. Not to change the spirit of the answer, but just to add details like:

- License information
- Price
- For each criteria of the original question, whether the proposed solution fits or not.

It is a way to make answers better, thus making the whole page more valuable to visitors. Comments can achieve the same but make it more laborious for the reader.